# Ruby on rails - Template missing prob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a hard time solving this problem because this is my first time to learn ruby on rail, i have a index.html.erb, new.html.erb, show.html.erb, edit.html.erb files. So when i go to localhost:3000/blogs/edit page the page that is showing is show.html.erb and when i delete the show.html.erb then access the edit.html.erb im having a template missing error. but when i access localhost:3000/blogs/new or just localhost:3000/blogs its working fine.So here's my code inside blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
        def index
            @content_first = 'This 1' ;
            @content_two = 'This 2' ;
        end

        def new

        end

        def create

        end

        def edit

        end

        def update

        end

        def show

        end

        def destroy

        end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're trying to access **/blogs/edit** , and the route is probably **/blogs/edit/:id**. As in you need to provide the id of a blog object, so that you can edit it.

If you run

```
rake routes
```

You will be able to see your available routes.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Now i get it, this is my first time to use this and still learning thank you btw for the answer!